Optimize Postgres Aggregation Query for Less CPU Usage
I’m running a query on around 2 million rows. Locally, it runs in around 2s (I have an M2 Mac 8 Core). On other hosting services with less cores, it can take around 12s. I’ve played around with some RDS instances and it seems like the query’s performance is more so dependent on the number of CPUs I have.
I have a materialized view (adjusted_events) which has a bunch of events in a hockey game. I want to create a table in which I can see the aggregated totals of each event by playerId. There's onIceFor/onIceAgainst columns (list of playerIds), which I unnest.
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW adjusted_events AS
SELECT
    "season",
    "gameId",
    "gameType",
    "gameState",
    "date",
    "event",
    "xG",
    "zone",
    "isOwnGoal",
    "situation",
    "situationOpp",
    "strength",
    "strengthOpp",
    "pulledGoalie",
    "emptyNet",
    "home",
    "away",
    UNNEST(
        CASE
            WHEN "event" = 'Blocked Shot' AND "reason" = 'teammate-blocked' THEN
                STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceAgainst"), ',')
            ELSE
                STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceFor"), ',')
        END
    )::int AS player_id,
    UNNEST(
        CASE
            WHEN "event" = 'Blocked Shot' AND "reason" = 'teammate-blocked' THEN
                STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceFor"), ',')
            ELSE
                STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceAgainst"), ',')
        END
    )::int AS opponent_id,
    STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "nZoneStart"), ',')::int[] AS nZoneStart,
    STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "oZoneStart"), ',')::int[] AS oZoneStart,
    STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "dZoneStart"), ',')::int[] AS dZoneStart,
    STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceHome"), ',')::int[] AS onIceHome,
    STRING_TO_ARRAY(TRIM(BOTH '[]' FROM "onIceAway"), ',')::int[] AS onIceAway
FROM event_data;

Here's the query of concern (there are a few unnecessary 'WHERE 1 = 1' since sometimes a different condition is dynamically added, but that is beyond the question):
WITH toi_cte (playerId, totalSeconds) AS (
        VALUES (8476822, 56455), ..., (8482145, 656)
      )
      SELECT * FROM (
        SELECT
          main.id,
          main.name,
          main.team,
          main.position_code,
          ROUND((toi_cte.totalSeconds::decimal / NULLIF(main.games, 0))::numeric, 2)::float AS toi_gp, -- Replacing TOI with TOI/gp
          ROUND((main.corsi_for::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS corsi_for, ROUND((main.corsi_against::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS corsi_against, ROUND((main.fenwick_for::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS fenwick_for, ROUND((main.fenwick_against::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS fenwick_against, ROUND((main.goals_for::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS goals_for, ROUND((main.goals_against::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS goals_against, ROUND((main.shots_for::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS shots_for, ROUND((main.shots_against::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS shots_against, ROUND((main.xg_for::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS xg_for, ROUND((main.xg_against::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS xg_against, ROUND((main.ozone_faceoffs::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS ozone_faceoffs, ROUND((main.dzone_faceoffs::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS dzone_faceoffs, ROUND((main.nzone_faceoffs::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS nzone_faceoffs, ROUND((main.ozone_starts::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS ozone_starts, ROUND((main.dzone_starts::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS dzone_starts, ROUND((main.nzone_starts::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS nzone_starts, ROUND((main.giveaways::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS giveaways, ROUND((main.takeaways::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS takeaways, ROUND((main.defensive_zone_giveaways::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS defensive_zone_giveaways, ROUND((main.offensive_takeaways::decimal / toi_cte.totalSeconds) * 3600, 2)::float AS offensive_takeaways, corsi_for_percentage, fenwick_for_percentage, goals_for_percentage, shots_for_percentage, xg_for_percentage, sh_percentage, sv_percentage, pdo, ozone_faceoff_percentage,
          main.games
        FROM
          (
    WITH filtered_adjusted_events AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM adjusted_events
      WHERE player_id IS NOT NULL
      AND "season" = 20232024
      AND ("gameType" = 'Regular')
      AND "date" < '2024-08-21'
  ), against_filtered_adjusted_events AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM adjusted_events
      WHERE opponent_id IS NOT NULL
      AND "season" = 20232024
      AND ("gameType" = 'Regular')
      AND "date" < '2024-08-21'
  ), player_game_counts AS (
      SELECT
          player_id,
          COUNT(DISTINCT "gameId") AS games
      FROM adjusted_events
    WHERE 1=1
      AND "gameType" = 'Regular'
      AND "season" = 20232024
      AND ("gameType" = 'Regular')
      AND "date" < '2024-08-21'
      GROUP BY player_id
  ), stats_for AS (
      SELECT 
          player_id,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss', 'Blocked Shot') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS corsi_for,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS fenwick_for,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Goal') AS goals_for,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS shots_for,
          ROUND(SUM("xG") FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0))::numeric, 2)::numeric AS xg_for,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Faceoff' AND "zone" = 'O') AS ozone_faceoffs,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Faceoff' AND "zone" = 'N') AS nzone_faceoffs,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE player_id = ANY (oZoneStart)) AS ozone_starts,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE player_id = ANY (nZoneStart)) AS nzone_starts,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Giveaway') AS giveaways,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Takeaway') AS takeaways,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Giveaway' AND "zone" = 'D') AS defensive_zone_giveaways,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Takeaway' AND "zone" = 'O') AS offensive_takeaways
      FROM filtered_adjusted_events
      WHERE 1=1
      GROUP BY player_id
  ), stats_against AS (
      SELECT 
          opponent_id AS player_id,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss', 'Blocked Shot') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS corsi_against,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS fenwick_against,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Goal') AS goals_against,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0)) AS shots_against,
          ROUND(SUM("xG") FILTER (WHERE "event" IN ('Goal', 'Shot on Goal', 'Miss') AND ("isOwnGoal" IS NULL OR "isOwnGoal" = 0))::numeric, 2)::numeric AS xg_against,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE "event" = 'Faceoff' AND "zone" = 'D') AS dzone_faceoffs,
          COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE opponent_id = ANY (dZoneStart)) AS dzone_starts
      FROM against_filtered_adjusted_events
      WHERE 1=1
      GROUP BY opponent_id
  ), final_stats AS (
      SELECT
          p.player_id AS id,
          p.full_name AS name,
          p.team_abbrevs AS team,
          p.position_code,
          COALESCE(f.corsi_for, 0)::int AS corsi_for,
          COALESCE(a.corsi_against, 0)::int AS corsi_against,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.corsi_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.corsi_against, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.corsi_for, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.corsi_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.corsi_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS corsi_for_percentage,
          COALESCE(f.fenwick_for, 0)::int AS fenwick_for,
          COALESCE(a.fenwick_against, 0)::int AS fenwick_against,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.fenwick_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.fenwick_against, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.fenwick_for, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.fenwick_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.fenwick_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS fenwick_for_percentage,
          COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0)::int AS goals_for,
          COALESCE(a.goals_against, 0)::int AS goals_against,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.goals_against, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.goals_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS goals_for_percentage,
          COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0)::int AS shots_for,
          COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0)::int AS shots_against,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS shots_for_percentage,
          COALESCE(f.xg_for, 0)::float AS xg_for,
          COALESCE(a.xg_against, 0)::float AS xg_against,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.xg_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.xg_against, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.xg_for, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.xg_for, 0) + COALESCE(a.xg_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS xg_for_percentage,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0) > 0 THEN 
                  (COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0)::numeric / COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0)) * 100
                  ELSE 
                  0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS sh_percentage,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0) > 0 THEN 
                  (1 - (COALESCE(a.goals_against, 0)::numeric / COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                  0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS sv_percentage,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0) > 0 AND COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0) > 0 THEN 
                  ((COALESCE(f.goals_for, 0)::numeric / COALESCE(f.shots_for, 0)) * 100) + ((1 - (COALESCE(a.goals_against, 0)::numeric / COALESCE(a.shots_against, 0))) * 100)
                  ELSE 
                  0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS pdo,
          COALESCE(f.ozone_faceoffs, 0)::int AS ozone_faceoffs,
          COALESCE(a.dzone_faceoffs, 0)::int AS dzone_faceoffs,
          COALESCE(f.nzone_faceoffs, 0)::int AS nzone_faceoffs,
          COALESCE(f.ozone_starts, 0)::int AS ozone_starts,
          COALESCE(a.dzone_starts, 0)::int AS dzone_starts,
          COALESCE(f.nzone_starts, 0)::int AS nzone_starts,
          ROUND(
              CASE 
                  WHEN (COALESCE(f.ozone_faceoffs, 0) + COALESCE(a.dzone_faceoffs, 0)) > 0 THEN 
                      (COALESCE(f.ozone_faceoffs, 0)::numeric / (COALESCE(f.ozone_faceoffs, 0) + COALESCE(a.dzone_faceoffs, 0))) * 100
                  ELSE 
                      0 
              END, 2
          )::float AS ozone_faceoff_percentage,
          COALESCE(f.giveaways, 0)::int AS giveaways,
          COALESCE(f.takeaways, 0)::int AS takeaways,
          COALESCE(f.defensive_zone_giveaways, 0)::int AS defensive_zone_giveaways,
          COALESCE(f.offensive_takeaways, 0)::int AS offensive_takeaways,
          COALESCE(pg.games, 0)::int AS games
      FROM players_info p
      LEFT JOIN stats_for f ON p.player_id = f.player_id
      LEFT JOIN stats_against a ON p.player_id = a.player_id
      LEFT JOIN player_game_counts pg ON p.player_id = pg.player_id
      WHERE p.season = 20232024
  ),
  final_stats_with_ranks AS (
      SELECT
          *
      FROM final_stats
  )
  SELECT *
  FROM final_stats_with_ranks
  WHERE position_code != 'G' AND games > 0   
  ORDER BY fenwick_for DESC
  ) AS main 
        LEFT JOIN
          toi_cte ON main.id = toi_cte.playerId
      ) AS subquery
      WHERE "toi_gp" > 0 AND games >= 0 order by corsi_for desc;

Is there a way to optimize this query further? Or is there a way to get more cores on a hosting service without getting insanely pricey? Thanks in advance, sorry if this is long.
I tried lowering the work_mem on my local machine to match the hosting DB's work_mem to see if there's any difference in performance, but this didn't change anything.
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the local (faster) query:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/mJnk
explain(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the hosting (slower) query, currently using Supabase:
https://explain.depesz.com/s/rWT7
Here are the indexes I added, which haven't resulted in a significant increase in performance:
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "game_type_index"   "CREATE INDEX game_type_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (""gameType"")"
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "season_index"  "CREATE INDEX season_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (season)"
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "date_index"    "CREATE INDEX date_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (date)"
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "event_index"   "CREATE INDEX event_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (event)"
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "on_ice_home_index" "CREATE INDEX on_ice_home_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (onicehome)"
"public"    "adjusted_events"   "on_ice_away_index" "CREATE INDEX on_ice_away_index ON public.adjusted_events USING btree (oniceaway)"


It's typically the Sequential Scans (Seq Scan) that impact performance if the displayed cost is high. It might help if you add an index on the fields shown in the Sequential Scans. Try adding one-at-a-time and see if it helps (eg gameType).

Materialized views can have indexes. Adding indexes to adjusted_events might reduce the number of sequential scans. I've only taken a brief look at the explain plan; however, season, gameType, and date seem to be good candidates. Avoid using reserved keywords, such as date, for column names. For readability, consider using snake case for identifiers (e.g., game_type instead of "gameType"):  doing so reduces the visual noise associated with an excessive number of " characters and makes the separate parts of the name standout more than using upper case..

Increase work_mem to something like 100MB to avoid the sort on disk.

You can put large plans (with BUFFFERS, and with track_io_timing set on) on https://explain.depesz.com/ and link to them.  Post one for the fast machine and one for the slow one.

@FrankHeikens I increased work_mem to 100MB but didn't see a difference in terms of the overall speed of the query. Perhaps I did something wrong

@JohnH Thanks for the advice on naming, I will begin renaming everything after I can figure out more on this question. You're definitely right about the visual noise.

The query plan says you're using 2184kB for work_mem, not 100MB. Did you reload the configuration after the change?

@FrankHeikens Check this one out, I made sure it was 100MB, now using a free tier RDS https://explain.depesz.com/s/mMJJ

The CTE player_game_counts costs you more than a second of execution time.
To speed up the query, either don't display that count at all or use a materialized view to hold a pre-computed value.

This speeds up the query (from 2s locally and 12s hosting to 1s locally to 6s hosting), however, the overall query remains 6x slower. I will re-evaluate the games.
